# Inconsistent layout with different length in <H1>

Tags: html, css

I am building my website and come across this tricky issue:

With the same external css, pages display differently (such as the about page and [experience page](http://www.willyuan.com/experience/)).

I've examined the difference between the two and tried several simple workarounds, none has worked. By noticing that the pagebody div is aligning with the page title, I have extended the page title to "Past Experience" ([example](http://www.willyuan.com/experience/experience.html)).

Can any of you help me to figure out the real problem? Is there an issue with the stylesheet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see my answer and let me know if i am lagging anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem can be fixed by adding the following:

```
#pagebody{clear: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add in css

```
#headline {
    float: left;
    width:100%;

}
```

result

[image]

Comment: I'm not a fan of using floats everywhere to fix the issue. Could you explain why your solution works?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to explain what clearing or containing floats is about, but my question to you in specific was about why floating the parent container as you are suggesting fixes the issue? It would be great if you improve your answer by explaining why something works in addition to just what fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your CSS:

```
#headline { overflow:hidden; }
```

Your problem here is that your floated nav and logo are not cleared / contained, so that the elements after the float can continue on the next line and return the normal document flow.

Also when you use floats, its better to have a `width` set on the floated elements. Width can be in any unit, `px`, `em` or `%`

You could also do this as an alternative:

```
#pagebody { clear:both; }
```

which is code to clear left and right floats and return `#pagebody` to normal document flow under `#headline`